# How to use chronicle-map instead of redis as a data cache

Tags: chronicle-map

I intend to use chronicle-map instead of redis, the application scenario is the memoryData module starts every day from the database to load hundreds of millions of records to chronicle-map, and dozens of jvm continue to read chronicle-map records. Each jvm has hundreds of threads. But probably because of the lack of understanding of the chronicle-map, the code poor performance, running slower, until the memory overflow. I wonder if the above practice is the correct use of chronicle-map.

Comment: The question should have a lot more details. Types of keys and values? Map sizes? What operations are called on Maps? How they are created? Working code snippets (maybe fake class names/data)?

Answer (score 0):

Because Chronicle map stores your data off-heap it's able to store more data than you can hold in main memory, but will perform better if all the data can fit into memory, ( so if possible, consider increasing your machine memory, if this is not possible try to use an SSD drive ), another reason for poor performance maybe down to how you have sized the map in the chronicle map builder, for example how you have set the number of max entries, if this is too large it will effect performance.